# bash script if elif statement

Tags: bash, shell

keep getting this error when I run the script, not sure what went wrong, this is if elif with or condition statement

line xx: ((: WEST - Very Big=EAST - BIG: syntax error in expression (error token is "WEST - Very Big")

```
echo "$yn"

if  (($yn=EAST - BIG)) || (($yn=EAST - SMALL))
    then
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> /tmp/"$HOSTNAME".log
elif  (($yn=WEST - Very Big)) || (($yn=WEST - Very Small))  
    then
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> /tmp/"$HOSTNAME".log
else
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> /tmp/"$HOSTNAME".log
    fi
```

Comment: Are West and very big variables? if yes, try: 1. delete the spaces, 2. $WEST - $VERY_BIG ? And next time post the all important parts of the script.

Comment: where are you setting the `yn` variable?

Comment: the $yn could be the  EAST - BIG, EAST - SMALL, WEST - Very Big, WEST - Very Small

Answer (score 2):

Several issues. The check for equality inside `(( ))` is `==` (a single `=` is an assignment).  This is common to many languages.

You are not allowed whitespace inside a variable name (assuming those are variable names).  The characters allowed in a variable name are ASCII alphanumerics or an underscore, and the first character cannot be a number.

It is also a bad idea to use all UPPERCASE for your own variable names.  The shell sets and uses a large number of UPPERCASE variables itself, and you could stomp on each other's values.

Here is my test version of your code:

```
yn=42
EAST=52
BIG=100
WEST=45
Very_Big=3
Very_Small=1
HOSTNAME='fred'

# Here I used a variable to avoid repeating myself
# that makes it easier to change the filename later
outfile="/tmp/$HOSTNAME.log"
> "$outfile"    # Zero the file

echo "$yn"

if  (($yn == EAST - BIG )) || (($yn == EAST - SMALL ))
then
    echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> "$outfile"
elif  (($yn == WEST - Very_Big )) || (($yn == WEST - Very_Small)) 
then
    echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> "$outfile"
else
    echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> "$outfile"
fi
```

Code is much easier to read when you use consistent indentation.  To trace how a bash program is running, use `-x`, for example:

```
bash -x myscript
```

Comment: after change = to == and remove the space, I no longer get the error but some logic problem if $yn value change but it always match the first condition  if  (($yn == EAST - BIG )) || (($yn == EAST - SMALL ))

I run with -x command get the following output

+ echo WEST - Very_Big 
WEST - Very_Big 

+ (( WEST - Very_Big  == EAST - BIG  ))

Comment: @Francis:  I have no idea what you are trying to achieve, so I can't debug logic problems for you.  If you gave some description of the problem you are trying to solve then I might be able to help.

Comment: $yn is variable that have many value EAST - BIG, EAST - SMALL, WEST - Very Big, WEST - Very Small and others, the script need first if test if the variable equal EAST - BIG or equal EAST - SMALL run this elif variable equal WEST - Very Big or WEST - Very Small run this, the rest run last else condition. the problem now is whatever $yn value is only match the first test EAST - BIG or equal EAST - SMALL